# components in react are imported but not visible when used

Tags: reactjs

created a react app when i try to import an module it is imported but when i used the component custom tag it says " 'component' is defined but never used " in the terminal and the data inside the custom tag that shoud be visible is not

```
import './App.css';
import navbar from "./bannerV"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <navbar/>

      hello

    </div>
  );
}
```

in this navbar is importd but component is not showing any of the things inside it it just shows hello

expecting a solution

Comment: All React component names must start with a capital letter. If you start a component name with a lowercase letter, it will be treated like a built-in element like a <div> or a <span>

Comment: Lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags.